# How to build a single source file of a kernel module

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module, kbuild

I want to compile a `.c` file into an `.o` file so that in a separate later stage I could link it with others to produce a loadable module (`.ko` file).

I tried to follow Kbuilds documentation (2.4 [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt)), but had no success:

```
obj-m: myfile.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$PWD/ myfile.o
```

The output is:

```
 $ make
cc    -c -o myfile.o myfile.c
myfile.c:42:26: fatal error: linux/printk.h: No such file or         directory
 #include <linux/printk.h>
                          ^
compilation terminated.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'myfile.o' failed
make: *** [myfile.o] Error 1
```

Comment: In the `all` receipt instead of `myfile.o` should be `modules` target.

Answer (score 1):

First thing, as you are getting fatal here regarding headers, so first include all required header file

```
#include <linux/module.h> /* Needed by all modules */
#include <linux/kernel.h> /* Needed for KERN_INFO */
#include <linux/init.h> /* Needed for the macros */
```

Second thing, in `Makefile` target should be `modules` instead of single `.o` file

```
obj-m += myfile.o
all:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
```

Comment: Ok, I chnaged everything you said additionally replaced `obj-m: myfile.o` with `+=`. Now I get the following error `arch/x86/Makefile:140: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support`.

Comment: I think you didn't install kernel properly ? open `vi /usr/src/linux-4.1.39/arch/x86/ +117` and check

Comment: This directory does not exist. I have a 64 bit kernel though and am able to build modules the regular way. Only compiling a single source into an object gives me the troubles :(

Comment: You do not need to have both `init.h` and `module.h` in the same driver. If you do this it means you aren't familiar with Linux kernel.